# HTML5 validity of nested tables

Tags: html, validation, datagrid, html-table, w3c

I'm looking for the specs of HTML5 in terms of tables.
I'm doing a web application has a lot of data tables.

These tables generally have one database row mapped to one table row. All is good.
However one particular problem child has so many columns that it needs to be spread over two rows in the table. So the ordinary tables are (in pseudo):

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Header</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>Data</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And the problematic row are like this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <th>Header row 1</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Header row 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Data</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

So my question is now: Is it valid to have nested tables in HTML5?
We can easily agree that it's very ugly. But I'm considering only validity here.

If I can have nested tables, it will solve any number of problems pertaining to sorting and editing of these tables (have a semi data-grid functionality implemented).
That way the main table can still consist of just one row with two columns. the sortable date and the embedded table with the data.

What do you say? I've been looking for the specs but couldn't find anything definite.

Comment: The easy way to find out: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I believe it's as valid as it ever was. But can't you achieve what you want with `rowspan` and `colspan`?

Comment: Yes. However it's 1) an intranet application and not publicly accessible and 2) I'd like to have a hint before I refactor the code,just to revert if it doesn't validate ;)

Comment: @OllyHodgson That's how it's implemented now. But it's messy in terms of scripting the editor and the sorting also gives me grief.

Comment: @JamesAllardice The W3 HTML5 validator is only experimental.

But yeah, nested tables should still be valid — I haven't heard anything to the contrary, and can't see why it shouldn't be.

Comment: @Nix That's what I'm hoping for. But since HTML5 saw quite a few changes and shakeups in terms of syntax and schema I was in doubt.

Comment: @Nix - Yes it is experimental but I haven't come across anything that is valid HTML5 that doesn't validate, and vice versa.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This document, which contains nothing but a nested table:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>A nested table</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Nested</td>
                                <td>Table</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

…is valid, according to http://validator.w3.org/nu/:

> The document validates according to the specified schema(s) and to additional constraints checked by the validator.

Comment: For some reason the validator doesn't work for me. But I take your work for it ;) Thanks :) Edit: Now it did after someone kicked a proxy. I luckily get the same result ;)

Answer (score -2):

Nested tables need to actually be nested within `<td>` elements which **in turn** are nested within `<tr>`'s and other tables, not just within the tables or rows directly.

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)

> `<table>` **Permitted Content**:
>
> - an optional `<caption>` element,
> - zero or more `<colgroup>` elements,
> - an optional `<thead>` element,
> - either one of the following:
> - zero or more `<tbody>` elements
> - one or more `<tr>` elements
> - an optional `<tfoot>` element
>
> `<tr>` **Permitted Content**:
>
> - Zero or more `<td>` and/or `<th>` elements; script-supporting elements (`<script>` and `<template>`) are also allowed
>
> `<td>` **Permitted Content**:
>
> - Flow content. (`<table>` is included in this list)

Comment: This is actually a good point, not explicitly documented (based on my search efforts). Nested tables need to be `<td>` elements in order to validate. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Advanced#Nesting_Tables